# C# console application developed with mono runs on windows but not on ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, mono, xamarin, ubuntu-12.10

I wrote a C# project to bring the attendance record from a finger print device using Xamarin studio.

The code runs when I click Run => Run with => Mono 3.0.6 from the menu and it also runs when I double click the exe file in the debug folder of the project. But when I try to run the application on an Ubuntu machine with mono run-time installed using the following command

```
mono MyApplication.exe
```

I get the following output

```
System.DllNotFoundException: FKAttend
at (wrapper managed-to-native) FingerPrint.mdlPublic:FK_ConnectNet
(int,string,int,int,int,int,int)
at testCSFB.MainClass.cmdOpenComm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at testCSFB.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: FKAttend
at (wrapper managed-to-native) FingerPrint.mdlPublic:FK_ConnectNet   (int,string,int,int,int,int,int)
at testCSFB.MainClass.cmdOpenComm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at testCSFB.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

`FKAttend` is the name of the `.dll` file but I think its embedded within the .`exe` file, because it run's on windows perfectly.

Does anyone know why this issue happens?

Comment: Are you sure it's not installed in the GAC on Windows? When you say you *think* it's embedded in the EXE - shouldn't you know, given that you built it?

Comment: Mono [does not support](http://www.mono-project.com/CPlusPlus) mixed-mode assemblies on platforms other than Windows.

Comment: Jon Skeet, you are right, I tried to add the DLL to GAC in Ubuntu
'gacutil -i FKAttend.dll' and I get the following output
'Failure adding assembly FKAttend.dll to the cache: The file specified is not a valid assembly.'

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/73664192/72836238-FKAttend-ManualA Almost clear that the dependency is only available on Windows, so your app won't run on Linux. You have to find a native finger print solution on Linux instead.